# Uploadify upload folder renaming

Tags: uploadify

I am using the latest flash version of `uploadify` (v3.2.1 I think). If I set the upload folder name to '**tempupload**' it doesn't upload (although **move_uploaded_file** returns **true**),

eg

This does not work

```
$targetFolder = '/path/tempupload';
```

this does work

```
$targetFolder = '/path/dave';
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: check the folder permission ?

Comment: My stupid mistake, an unlink function buried in a $.post file was removing the uploads.